# Get the text which is found inside a nested Div tag using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the text between nested div but unable to get the text(TEXT HERE).The text is found inside the nested div. text here. So as you see below i want to print out the text(TEXT HERE) which is found inside all those 'div',as the text is not inside a 'p' tag i was unable to print the text. I am using BeautifulSoup to extract the text.When i run the code below ,it does not print out anything.
The structure of the 'div' is

```
<div class="_333v _45kb".....
    <div class="_2a_i" ...............
        <div class="_2a_j".......</div>
        <div class="_2b04"...........
            <div class="_14v5"........
                <div class="_2b06".....
                    <div class="_2b05".....</div>
                    <div id=............>**TEXT HERE**</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
theurl = "here URL"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.praser")
comm_list = soup.findAll('div', class_="_333v _45kb")
for lists in comm_list:
    print(comm_list.find('div').text)
```

Comment: Please show your code [mcve]. In this case it looks like you can access div tag by id and then get `text` property

Comment: @buran i updated the question. you can see the code there now

Comment: what is the id of the most nested div - `<div id=............>**TEXT HERE**</div>`? That's the div you want to find and there is no info about it, so that we can help. You don't need all the rest, the loop, etc.

Comment: @buran the id is different for each text so as there is no common id for all text i cant use it

Comment: OP wants to scrape FB comments (see comments in my answer). This needs much more focus. As it stands it's XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

Beacuse OP continue to not provide enough information, here is sample

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="spam">Some Spam Here</div>
        <div id="eggs">**TEXT HERE**</div>
    </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# This will print all the text
div = soup.find('div', {'class':'foo'})
print(div.text)


print('\n----\n')
# if other divs don't have id
for div in soup.findAll('div'):
    if div.has_attr('id'):
        print(div.text)
```

output

```
Some Spam Here
**TEXT HERE**


---------
**TEXT HERE**
```

Comment: When i run the code using your sample it returns :AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text': The error occur on print(div.text) part of (# This will print all the text part ) in your above sample

Comment: it works for me, I have no idea what you are doing. see https://repl.it/repls/PlumImpureClosedsource

Comment: What i want to get is the text in the comments.see https://repl.it/repls/ProperHelpfulNet

Comment: So, this turns out to be XY problem - you want to scrape comments from Facebook. You know you need to log in first in order to view it, right? And the best approach would be to just use Facebook API, instead of screen scrapping.

Comment: I did logged in first then execute this,So you are saying there is no way other than Facebook API to scrape the comment

Comment: No, I don't say that. But it's the better option. As to logging - you need to provide credentials in the script, then replicate requests made from the browser with cookies and all

Comment: But what exactly wrong with my code. Why do you think it is not getting the text